# PHP looping through 2 sets of images in array

Tags: php, image, loops

I have 2 sets of images in the same folder that I'm using for my uploader. what is the best way to loop href links to the large images as well as the thumbnails so that once looped, they can be linked together. here is the code I have so far:

```
$folder = 'uploads/';
$filetype = '*.*';
$files = glob($folder.$filetype);
$count = count($files);
echo '<table>';

//looping all images
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo '<tr><td>';
    echo '<a name="'.$i.'" href="#'.$i.'"><img src="'.$files[$i].'" /></a>';
    //echo substr($files[$i],strlen($folder),strpos($files[$i], '.')-strlen($folder));
    echo '</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: How can you distinguish between large file and thumbnail? And having both in the same dir for the sake of having only one loop isn't a good design imo

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function **getimagesize();** if all thumnails are of same size.

Example

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("IMG_LOCATION/IMAGE.EXT");
```

and then you can filter the thumnails from largsize images

```
$thumbnail = array();
$large_img = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($files[$i]);
    if($width == The width of thumbnail){
        $thumbnail[] = $files[$i];
    }else{
        $large_img[] = $files[$i];
    }

}
```

Now you can display all thumbnail by looping through the array $thumbnail and large images by looping through $large_img